# How to limit a search of a directory with "find" command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to make a Bash script that would create symlinks to directories that have a "target" subdirectory. I use "find" command to search for the "target" directories and put the filepaths to array.

```
array_of_dirs=( $(find -type d -name "target") )
```

The array is looped through and symbolic links are made to directories.
My issue is that the depth of the directory structure is unknown and the subdirectories can have multiple "target" directories.

The directory structure could be:

```
    .
    ├── blaah
    │   ├── jee1
    │   │   └── omg1
    │   │       └── bar1
    │   │           └── target <--- When this is found, no need to continue into subdirectories
    │   │               └── wtf1
    │   │                   └── target
    │   ├── jee2
    │   │   └── target
    │   ├── jee3
    │   └── jee4
    └── blaah2
        ├── jou1
        │   └── target
        ├── jou2
        └── jou3
            └── target <--- When this is found, no need to continue into subdirectories
                ├── foo1
                │   └── target
                ├── foo2
                │   └── target
                └── foo3
                    └── target
```

At the moment these paths are found and there are unwanted symbolic links created.

```
    ./blaah/jee1/omg1/bar1
    ./blaah/jee1/omg1/bar1/target/wtf1 <--- Unwanted
    ./blaah/jee2
    ./blaah2/jou1
    ./blaah2/jou3
    ./blaah2/jou3/target/foo1 <--- Unwanted
    ./blaah2/jou3/target/foo2 <--- Unwanted
    ./blaah2/jou3/target/foo3 <--- Unwanted
```

How could I limit that when the "target" is found the search will not continue further into the subdirectories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest solution first, even if it was found at last (suggested by Eastman himself in a comment).

```
array_of_dirs=($(find -type d -name "foo" -prune))
```

With the -path option, you may exclude paths, containing the whole token "/target/". In contrast to -name, which only evaluates the filename itself, the path needs globbing to catch foo/target and target/bar. And of course it needs negation -not -path "*/target/*".

```
array_of_dirs=($(find -type d -not -path "*/target/*" -name "target"))
```

With a test on my system and foo instead of target:

```
find -type d -name "foo" 
./tmp/bar/bar/foo
./tmp/bar/foo
./tmp/test/bar/foo
./tmp/foo
./tmp/foo/foo
./tmp/foo/foo/foo

find -type d -not -path "*/foo/*" -name "foo" 
./tmp/bar/bar/foo
./tmp/bar/foo
./tmp/test/bar/foo
./tmp/foo
```

The option -path ... -prune seems to have the same effect. For detailed differences, please study the manual carefully. A short test revealed a 10% time benefit by using prune, but it can be a caching effect or random influence.

(needlessly verbose intermediate solution:)

<strike>find -type d -name "foo" -path "*/foo*" -prune</strike>

Comment: Just adding `-prune` seems to be exactly what I was looking for. This works as I intended `array_of_dirs=( $(find -type d -name "target" -prune) )`.  _Action: -prune, If the file is a directory, do not descend into it._ source: https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html

Comment: Fine. Imported into my answer and put to top, because of tl;dr.

Answer (score 2):

Filter the unwanted results.

```
array_of_dirs=( $(find -type d -name "target" | grep -v target/) )
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer would have worked also, but `-prune` seems to be more efficient as it prevents traversing into the sub directories of "target".

Answer (score 0):

You can force the `find` command to stop right after finding the first match:

```
find dir pattern -print -quit
```

Comment: Wouldn't that stop the whole process and just return the first dir `target`?

Answer (score 0):

Before creating the symlink, put an if condition to check if the directory found out is not a sub-directory of an already found target directory :

```
if [ $( echo ${DIR} | grep -o "target" | wc -l) -eq 1 ] 
then
    # create symlink 
fi
```

Also, I'm not sure how the result of

```
find -type d -name "target"
```

should include "./blaah/jee1/omg1/bar1/target/wtf1" . What OS are you on?

Comment: I'm scripting with Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, but using the script on CentOS 7. `find -type d -name "target"` includes "./blaah/jee1/omg1/bar1/target/wtf1", because wtf1 has subdir "target"
I put a condition check that before creating the symlinks, but this can be inefficient as there can be a lot of sub directories after the first "target" directory.